# Why does Assert.AreEqual(x, y) fail, but Assert.AreEqual(y, x) doesn't?

Tags: c#, struct, assert, equality

Consider this struct:

```
public struct MyNumber
{
    private readonly int _value;

    public MyNumber(int myNumber)
    {
        _value = myNumber;
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is MyNumber)
            return this == (MyNumber) obj;

        if (obj is int)
            return Value == (int)obj;

        return false;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }

    public static implicit operator int(MyNumber myNumber)
    {
        return myNumber.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyNumber(int myNumber)
    {
        return new MyNumber(myNumber);
    }
}
```

When I do this in a unit test:

```
Assert.AreEqual(new MyNumber(123), 123);
```

It's green.

But this test fails:

```
Assert.AreEqual(123, new MyNumber(123));
```

Why is this so? I'm guess it's because the int class determines the equality, whereas in the first case, my class determines it. But my class is implicitly convertible to `int`, so shouldn't that help?

How can I make the Assert.AreEqual work in both ways? I'm using MSTest by the way.

**Update**

Implementing `IEquatable<int>` or `IComparable<int>` doesn't help.

Comment: Wonder if it might be worth implementing `IEquatable`?

Comment: @Charleh: It is worth implemeting `IEquatable<T>` if you are going to store your values in a collection. It will speed up operations like `Contains`, `IndexOf` etc.

Comment: Not `IEquatable` @Charleh, `IComparable<int>`. This will ensure that the class works with `Greater` and `Less` assertions as well.

Comment: Which unit testing framework are you using? Are you asserting using `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert` or are you using a different unit testing framework?

Comment: Good question, I'm using MSTest indeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first assertion will invoke `MyNumber.Equals` and you have implemented in a way where it will succeed if the argument to compare to is an `Int32` and it is equal to value of `MyNumber`.

The second assertion will invoke `Int32.Equals` and it will fail because the argument to compare to is an `MyNumber` which `Int32` does not know about or understand.

You cannot make your second unit test succeed because you assert that an `Int32` should be equal to your value. It cannot be because it is different. It is the code in `Int32.Equals` that decides if the second value is equal. You have implemented some casting operators that you can unit test so these assertions should work:

```
Assert.AreEqual(123, (int) new MyNumber(123));
Assert.AreEqual((MyNumber) 123, new MyNumber(123));
```

Even though the casts are implemented `implicit` they will not automatically be invoked by `Assert.AreEquals` because this method expect two parameters of type `Object` and you will have to invoke them explicitly as I did above.

Because of the special handling in your `MyNumber.Equals` you now have a type that is not commutative with regards to equals, e.g. `MyNumber(123) equals Int32(123)` is true but `Int32(123) equals MyNumber(123)` is false. You should avoid that so I recommend that you remove the special case handling of ints in `MyNumber.Equals` and instead rely on the implicit casts which will work for you most of the time. And when they do not you will have to make an explicit cast.

Comment: But if the MyNumber would be class, whitch implement interface IEquatable i think, that the both assertion will be ok. doesn't it?

Comment: @Davecz: I believe that `Assert.AreEqual` basically maps to the static `Object.Equals` which after doing a few simple checks will invoke `objA.Equals(objB)`. I do not believe that the generic interface `IEquatable<T>` is used in this process.

Comment: Implementing `IComparable` as I noted below will solve the OP's problem.

Comment: This answer doesn't cover the OP's question "How can I make the Assert.AreEqual work in both ways?"

Comment: @MartinLiversage: I think IEquatable overrides Object.Equals, because if I'm not mistaken, Object.Equals uses reflection to compare and if it is implemented interface IEquatable is Equal method faster and better for perfomance, but I'm not sure. Of course you can call base method (Object.Equal) at the end of your ovveriden method. but I think that IEquatable has higher priority then Object.Equals

Comment: @RobEpstein: `IComparable` is about being less than, equal to or greater than, e.g. it used for sorting. This interface is not used when comparing equality which this questions seems to be about.

Comment: @Davecz: The static method `Object.Equals` does not use reflection. After some simple checks it calls the virtual `Object.Equals` method that each value type has to implement correctly to make things work. `IEquatable<T>` is used by some collections to speed up comparisons by using a strongly typed `Equals` method.

Comment: @MartinLiversage: you have right. Object.Equals does not use a reflexion. But IEquatable is used for strongly type equality. In my project i used it for faster comparsion between objects in collection. I have to read more information about implementation these base methods :-)
Thanks for explanation...

Answer (score 2):

To quote from [`Object.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The following statements must be true for all implementations of the Equals(Object) method. In the list, x, y, and z represent object references that are not **null**.
>
> - ...
> - x.Equals(y) returns the same value as y.Equals(x).

Your `Equals` implementation breaks this hard requirement. `((object)x).Equals(123)` *must* return the same value as `((object)123).Equals(x)`, if `x` is not `null`, regardless of what type it has.

There's a whole lot of code out there that, correctly, assumes that it doesn't matter which of the two objects is asked to perform the comparison. Design your code so that that assumption is not invalidated.

Effectively, this means that you *must* design your class in such a way that it *doesn't* compare equal to any integer type, no matter how much you might prefer otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `IComparable<int>` in your `MyNumber` struct as follows:

```
    public int CompareTo(int other)
    {
        return other.CompareTo(Value);
    }
```

This will ensure all Asserts work as expected such as:

```
    Assert.AreEqual(new MyNumber(123), 123);
    Assert.AreEqual(123, new MyNumber(123));
    Assert.Greater(124, new MyNumber(123));
    Assert.Less(124, new MyNumber(125));
```

Comment: The struct works as designed in Asserts comparing two `MyNumber`s

Comment: This doesn't work. As Martin mentions in the comments on his answer, IComporable is for sorting and ordering. It isn't called with Assert.AreEqual.

Comment: This might work in your unit testing framework which apparently by the occurence of `Assert.Greater` and `Assert.Less` is different from the MSTest unit testing framework used in the question but it fails if you use MSTest.

Comment: The original question at the time of my answer did not mention the test framework used so I provided an answer that works perfectly in NUnit. I will try to find a solution that works in MSTest.